# can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/: Permission denied with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Nice holidays.

One of my wordpress hosted with Godaddy. Which shows an error

```
can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/: Permission denied
```

when posting comments. But there is no directory exist in specified path(/var/spool/clientmqueue/)
Anybody can help me to solve this.

Answer (score -2):

It's related to the mail sender. Email messages stay in that directory before they are getting sent (the directory isn't a http directory, so you won't see it in your public_html)

If your wordpress server user doesn't have the required privileges, it will halt when trying to email you that a new comment has been added. You should ask you host about changing the permissions to for `/var/spool/clientmqueue/` (or do it yourself, if you have root access).

Comment: Changing /var/spool/clientmqueue will get you up and running, but doesn't solve the root cause.  Something else is broken to cause this.  clientmqueue is supposed to be locked down.